# The Lie Algebra of a trivial Lie Group

Tags: lie-groups

I was wondering if it is true that the lie algebra of a trivial lie group is trivial? Surely the answer is yes but I just want to make sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the trivial group as a 0-dimensional manifold. The corresponding Lie-algebra is defined as $T_e G$, which, seen as a vector space has the dimension of the manifold, hence $0$.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Thank you for the reply!

Comment: Maybe worth noting that far more generally (but as a consequence of this), *any finite group* with the discrete topology is a $0$-dimensional Lie group, and has the zero space as Lie algebra.